# Pandas works in Ipython but can't find module in OSX terminal

Tags: python, pandas

I use Python in OSX using Spyder and was recently trying to run a .py file through the command line. Pandas is installed and I've had no problem using it, but when I attempt to run the file or use Python interactively in the terminal, it's unable to find the Pandas module.

No problem with this when I run it in Spyder with the Ipython console:

```
import pandas as pd
xl = pd.ExcelFile("DDC_Report.xlsx")
```

However, when I attempt to import pandas in the Unix terminal, I get the following error.

```
>>> import pandas as pd
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named pandas
```

Running script from terminal:

```
abraham-mathew:~ abraham.mathew$ python Automation_Stacia.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Automation_Stacia.py", line 12, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
ImportError: No module named pandas
```

I'm' running the following:

```
    abraham-mathew:~ abraham.mathew$ python
Python 2.7.8 (v2.7.8:ee879c0ffa11, Jun 29 2014, 21:07:35) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

Can anyone help me identify what could be wrong. I'm at a total loss, but have the feeling it may be fairly simple. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I haven't worked with Spyder, but this might be a different environment under Spyder or under your normal command line. Try running the following using both methods. Is there a difference in the value of the environment variable `PYTHONPATH`?

```
import os
print os.getenv('PYTHONPATH')
```

Comment: Ah, looks like the path on Spyder and from terminal are different.

Comment: From Command Line: >>> print(os.getenv('PYTHONPATH')) 
None  From Spyder: /Applications/Spyder.app/Contents/Resources